# Failing to understand use of one-dimensional upper limit in area variable

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields, capacitance, gauss-law, integration

[image: see this]

I am trying to learn capacitance of a parallel plate capacitor, while learning i noticed the portion where they are calculating potential using line integral. Now, there is a term "ds" which is the small area of a plate of the capacitor, now what i dont understand is that how is it possible to use the upper limit x(which is the distance between the capacitors, one dimensional) in ds(which is area, two dimensional)? Likewise how is it possible to convert 'ds' into 'dx' ?

Comment: Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/10563), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020) instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\vec{ds}$ *is* a line element (not an area element). $\vec E \cdot \vec{ds}$ is the energy change in moving a unit charge by $\vec{ds}$ in a field $\vec E$.

However you are right to query the textbook (and maybe having the picture does help as it shows it's not an error in transcription.). The $x$ in the limit cannot be the same as the $dx$ in the integral. Strictly that should be written with another name, maybe $dx'$ or maybe $ds$. Or you could keep the $dx$ and take the limits  as from $0$ to $d$ (from the diagram).

Though actually this is the sort of mistake which is easy to make and easy for the reader so spot, so don't be too hard on the author. (If your teacher deducted marks for such a slip I guess you'd feel hard done by.)

Comment: Now i get it, actually i have been used to interpreting $ds$ as "elementary area" as most of the equations/text books use $ds$  symbol as "elementary" area.

Answer (score 1):

As you say, this is a line integral, so $d\vec{s}$ is not an infinitesimal area, but an infinitesimal line element.

Answer (score 0):

The electric field between the plates depends on the distance between them rather than the area of the plates - the area would tell you the total "amount" of electric field you have got but the actual strength of it at any point between the plates is given by the distance between the charged plates. So it makes sense that ds is a small portion of distance not area.